# What to do When Unicorn Type Error Happened in Ruby 2.4

Tags: ruby, unicorn, ruby-2.4

I upgrade ruby from 2.1 to 2.4(ruby24, ruby24-devel), bundler(version: 1.17.3), nokogiri(version: 1.6.8), rails(version: 4.0.1), unicorn(version: 5.0.1), therubyracer(version: 0.12.3).
There are failures as follows:

```
> INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
> /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282:
> warning: circular argument reference - now
> /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/rbhive-0.5.1/lib/rbhive/t_c_l_i_schema_definition.rb:10:
> warning: key :bigint is duplicated and overwritten on line 14
> /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:50:in
> `*': ActiveSupport::Duration can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)
>         from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:50:in
> `days'
>         from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:55:in
> `weeks'
>         from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise.rb:131:in
> `<module:Devise>'
>         from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise.rb:8:in
> `<top (required)>'
>         from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in
> `require'
>         from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in
> `block (2 levels) in require'
>         from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in
> `each'
```

I wonder if anyone knows what to do

Answer (score 1):

This is coming from `activesupport` gem which is used by `rails`. So there is a version compatibility issue between your `rails` and `ruby` versions. If you want to upgrade your `ruby`, sometimes you should upgrade your `rails` version accordingly. So there are 2 ways to crack down this issue. Downgrading the ruby version or upgrading the rails version gradually.

Comment: my ruby version currently is 2.4.5, and rails 4.0.1. should I upgrade my rails to 4.2.11??

Comment: @yfqin yes you should. But there would some complications regarding to used `gems` and your code. If you do not have a test coverage, doing such a major upgrade would lead problems. I mean do the upgrading gradually such as `4.0.1`, `4.0.2`, `4.0.3` so on up until the issue is resolved.

Comment: It seems not work when rails version=4.0.x or 4.1.x. I upgrade rails to 4.2.11 and other dependencies, but another error occurs:  Bundler Error Backtrace: from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.4/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in require'